# python code that guy on youtube did in jupyter notebook doesn't work for me in visual studio

Tags: python

I just started learning python with youtube videos and so I was writing code exactly like the guy on video was it worked for him but doesn't work for me :( I'm using Visual Studio and that guy was using Jupyter Notebook other than that the code is the same

```
name1 = "Arnošt"
height1 = 1.8
weight1 = 80

name2 = "Adolf"
height2 = 1.7
weight2 = 70

name3 = "Gertrůda"
height3 = "1.8"
weight3 = 90

def bmi_calc(name, height, weight):
 #apparently it has problem with this line :(
    bmi = weight / (height ** 2)
    print("bmi:")
    print(bmi)
    if bmi < 25:
        return name + " is not overweight"
    else:
        return name + " is overweight"

result1 = bmi_calc(name1, height1, weight1)
result2 = bmi_calc(name2, height2, weight2)
result3 = bmi_calc(name3, height3, weight3)

print(result1)
print(result2)
print(result3)
```

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Comment: Statement `height3 = "1.8"` is inconsistent with the other height assignments.  It should be: `height3 = 1.8`.

Comment: I guess he is getting a `TypeError` because height3 is a string in your case, but you want it to be a number (`height3 = 1.8`).

Answer (score 4):

You have used string value for `height3` variable.

Your mistake `height3 = "1.8"`

**Corrected code:**

```
name1 = "Arnošt"
height1 = 1.8
weight1 = 80

name2 = "Adolf"
height2 = 1.7
weight2 = 70

name3 = "Gertrůda"
height3 = 1.8
weight3 = 90

def bmi_calc(name, height, weight):
 #apparently it has problem with this line :(
    bmi = weight / (height ** 2)
    print("bmi:")
    print(bmi)
    if bmi < 25:
        return name + " is not overweight"
    else:
        return name + " is overweight"

result1 = bmi_calc(name1, height1, weight1)
result2 = bmi_calc(name2, height2, weight2)
result3 = bmi_calc(name3, height3, weight3)

print(result1)
print(result2)
print(result3)
```

Answer (score 0):

`height3` in your case, is a string, while it should be a float. Hence, on doing `height ** 2`, it raises an error, because a string cannot be raised to the power 2. Also, you are trying to divide a float with a string, `weight3 / height3`, which is wrong. Your correct code should be

```
name1 = "Arnošt"
height1 = 1.8
weight1 = 80

name2 = "Adolf"
height2 = 1.7
weight2 = 70

name3 = "Gertrůda"
height3 = 1.8
weight3 = 90

def bmi_calc(name, height, weight):
 #apparently it has problem with this line :(
    bmi = weight / (height ** 2)
    print("bmi:")
    print(bmi)
    if bmi < 25:
        return name + " is not overweight"
    else:
        return name + " is overweight"

result1 = bmi_calc(name1, height1, weight1)
result2 = bmi_calc(name2, height2, weight2)
result3 = bmi_calc(name3, height3, weight3)

print(result1)
print(result2)
print(result3)
```